# What is the output of the following python code snippet? (Topic : if-else statement)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone please explain this code snippet in python?

```
for i in range(0, 10, 2):
    if (i % 5 == 0):
        print(i)
```

Comment: What part is confusing?

Comment: Like I see the output is 0. Why not 0, 10? I'm unable to debug it? I want to know how 'i' is taking the values?

Comment: add `print(i)` before the `if` - it may help you to understand.

Comment: Because Python ranges always exclude the high end.  You'll get 0, 2, 4, 6, 8.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot.

Comment: The title mentions an `else`, but where is it?

Answer (score 1):

1. Iterate through `i`, where `i` = 0, 2, 4, 6, 8
2. If `i` mod 5 = 0, then print that value of `i`

Note that since we iterate through even numbers, `i` mod 5 will never be zero except for `i = 0`. You're not going to get 10 mod 5, because in Python you iterate up to and not including the last number.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(0, 10, 2): # iterates from 0 to 10 by incrementing 2 each time  
    if (i % 5 == 0):      # if i's are divided by 5 and remainder is 0  
        print(i)          # print i's
```

I tried to explain it in the simplest way.